# Azure Devops group variable to Docker compose file

Tags: docker, azure-devops, docker-compose

Have a question , i have many variables (mostly secrets defined as group variable in azure devops), i download the variables  in my azure pipeline , my requirement pass this group variables based on the environment to my docker compose.yml file which build my container, the issue is the group variable is not passed to my Docker compose can some one help here ??

group: accountapplication-test-${{ parameters.targetEnvironment}} (this has all my secrets based on environment )

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    image: ${REPOSITORY_URL}:latest
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        PAT: ${pat}  == ((this value is same for all env and should be picked from .env file)
    environment:
      genreric_variable : $(this value is same for all env and should be picked from .env file)
      ClientSettings__CreateClientId: ${ClientSettings__CreateClientId}
      ClientSettings__CreateClientSecret: ${ClientSettings__CreateClientSecret}
      ClientSettings__CreateClientScope: ${ClientSettings__CreateClientScope}
```

azure-pipeline.yml

```
  - stage:
    displayName: Testing on ${{ parameters.targetEnvironment  }}
    pool:
          vmImage: ubuntu-20.04
    jobs:
      - job: test
        variables:
          - group: accountapplication-test-${{ parameters.targetEnvironment}}
          
            value: ${{ parameters.targetEnvironment }}
        displayName: Test running in ${{ parameters.targetEnvironment }} environment

        steps:
              - script: |
                    date
                    docker-compose run app 
                env:
                  PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
                 
                  
                displayName: Build and Test
```

```
.env file (these are all same for all environment )

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
pat=${PAT}
APP_PORT=8080
REPOSITORY_URL=app
introspect_username                 = "phd2"
```

i tried in Docker compose file as  ClientSettings__CreateClientId: ${ClientSettings__CreateClientId} , in my group variable one of the variable is ClientSettings__CreateClientId in my azure devops. The pipeline expect all the variable declered in docker compose.yml should come from group variables ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [ReplaceToken](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task before the `docker-compose` script to replace the variables with their values, a very basic sample is below:

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens in docker-compose'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
     docker-compose.yml
    verbosity: detailed
    # use a different pattern here to differentiate variable groups
    # that way env file variables will work as is
    tokenPrefix: '#{'  
    tokenSuffix: '}#'
```

So use `#{ClientSettings__CreateClientId}#` instead of `${ClientSettings__CreateClientId}` in your environment variables

Comment: Thanks @sibtain , that worked but i have many general variables whose values  will be same and used by all the environments like both test acc and prod  for that i keep .env file which has all the generic values docker compose by default use this .env file , by using replacing token any variables i specify below environments in docker compose file it is expecting from group variables , is their any way where any generic values declared in docker compose file will pick the value from .env file ??

Comment: just update my question , if their is any way that will be great

Comment: If your generic variables are working as is as of now, you can try using different pattern (by changing `tokenPrefix` & `tokenSuffix`) for the variables coming from `variable group`. See my updated answer to get the idea.

Comment: great tip Sibtain , it worked , cheers